# MacType in Notepad++

Tags: fonts, notepad++, antialiasing

I'm sure many of you use MacType to antialias smaller fonts on windows. Unfortunately, Notepad++ contains it's own font rendering (or so I think). Any tips on how to get MacType working in Notepad++?

Comment: What makes you think it contains its own font rendering?  What have you altered in the Style Configuration to test?

Comment: Yes, I've tried quite a few different configurations. What makes me think it has it's own rendering system is that it, even when the system is rendering things using mactype, still doesn't antialias smaller font-sizes. If it does antialias, it's using the old windows method.